# Azure websites and session state

Tags: session-state, azure-web-app-service

I can't seem to get a straight answer about session state on Azure websites. Whether I am using SQL based or Azure caching, do I need to worry about machine keys when using multiple instances?

On a standard mode website, increasing the instances means separate VMs servicing requests with round robin load balancing. The contents of session get encrypted using the machine key so I need to ensure the keys are aligned on the instances. Is this taken care of by Azure?

Comment: For the sake of correctness/completeness: According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0bf53494-d547-4085-b467-efa908a9e751) Azure websites uses [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to create affinity/sticky sessions and not round robin.